# how to display speed of internet connection in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bandwidth

I have a asp.net web application that uses C#. It logs in on a remote machine and download files from the server. I wish to display bandwidth available during the connection or the speed of connection.

What could be the best possible way if I m not allowed to use any external library or APIs? How can I implemet it using Javascript?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following page:

[Determining available bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149211/determining-available-bandwidth)

It suggests there isnt really an easy way of doing it.

This one has some ideas of how to do it though:

[Detecting network connection speed and bandwidth usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566139/detecting-network-connection-speed-and-bandwidth-usage-in-c-sharp)

Hope they help.

Comment: Oh... That was really helpful.. but U know THIS IS ASP.NET. I havn't heard anything impossible here yet. There must be some way or the other for doing this the ASP.NET way.

Answer (score 1):

This article does a good job of explaining how [Google Analytics calculates speed](http://www.seifi.org/javascript/how-google-analytics-determines-connection-speeds.html).

As suggested by the article one of the easiest to implement but least accurate ways could be to implement / build a solution that matches the users IP address against the ISP that IP address belongs to, then "assume" the connection speed. I personally feel this would be way too inaccurate but it might be enough for your needs, especially if you are working on an application running over a closed WAN.